# Getting warnings for implicit conversion overflow from unsigned to signed

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, overflow, implicit-conversion

Consider the following problematic code:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int64_t y) {
    std::cout << y << "\n";
}

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 14400000000000000000ull;
    foo(x);
}
```

Typically prints `-4046744073709551616`.

How can one get the compiler to help with this type of conversion/overflow issue? I have tried the following:

```
g++ -g overflow.cpp -fsanitize=undefined -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -Wconversion
clang++ -g overflow.cpp -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

None of which gives any compile- or run-time warning.

(clang version 7.0.0, gcc version 8.2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `-Wconversion` is only going to warn if the value, when cast back to the source type, may not be the same type.  For example if `foo` were to take an `int` instead then `-Wconversion` will issue a warning because it is possible that you can't cast the value in the `int` back to the original `uint64_t` value.  If we have

```
uint64_t u = some_value;
int64_t s = static_cast<int64_t>(u);
uint64_t check = static_cast<uint64_t>(s)
```

then `check == u` will always be true (so long as `int64_t` is also two's compliment) so `-Wconversion` will not issue a warning because we get the source value back.

What you'll need in this case is

```
-Wsign-conversion
```

which will warning you that the signs mismatch.

Comment: I don't think `check == u` is guaranteed to be true. It will be true on 2's complement system though.

Answer (score 1):

GCC and Clang both have the warning option -Wsign-conversion to issue a warning in cases like this.

> warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int64_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-conversion]

Note GCC's documentation about -Wconversion

> ... Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

Also note that the program is well-formed (thus must compile succesfully) and has no undefined behaviour (and thus no reason to trigger the sanitizer). Converting unrepresentable number to signed results in implementation defined value.

Comment: I would have hoped that filling a variable with a "implementation defined value" triggers the sanitizer.